# Junit test by passing file path string and IOException handling inside private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit5

I have a private method called from the main() method to which I am passing the input file path as an argument. My code-under-test is the main() method. Somewhere in the middle of the private method, the file is read and some operations performed.

How can I:

**1. Pass the file path of String type ("src/test/resources/test.txt") as an argument.** I am getting **FileNotFoundException** if I pass the file path.

**2. How can I test an IOException that is handled in private method on not finding the file?**

Adding my code snippets here:

**Code under Test:**

```java
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyApp().readFile(args);
    }

    private void readFile(String[] args) {
        if (args != null) {
            String file = args[0];
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    // More business logic here for processing that line
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test for main:**

```java
    @Test
    void mainTest() {
        String[] args = {"/test_input.txt"};
        MyApp.main(args);
        assertNotNull(<some_object_after_processing>);
    }
```

Comment: Please add an example with your code under test and the test that you've written so far, so that the community can help you.

Comment: Have added code snippets

Answer (score 0):

To get file path you can use suitable way mentation in [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-src-test-resources-directory-path)
There is no need to check any assertion for `main` method.
If the test case is completed successfully then it passed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for raising your queries! First, you need to change your application code because you are reading a single file from the args[0] position then why you are going to read the strings array [File Array or collection of files].

1] Create 'resources' folder in your project:

Right-click on project and create a folder with name 'resources'.

2] Create 'test.txt' into the 'resources' folder.

3] Modified code:

```
package com.application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyApp().readFile("resources/Test.txt");
    }
    private void readFile(String fileName) {
        if (fileName != null) {

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    // More business logic here for processing that line
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, You can pass a fileName directly to the method. I hope that it will help you to resolve your first query.